# Is it possible to have a static member variable in my templated class, without the class's user having to know about it?

Tags: c++, templates, static, member-variables

I have a templated container class, something like this toy code:

```
template <class ItemType> class MyVector
{
public:
   MyVector() : _numItems(0), _items(NULL) {/* empty */}

   /** Returns a reference to the first item in our array,
     * or a default-constructed item if the array is empty.
     */
   const ItemType & GetFirstItemWithDefault() const
   {
      return (_numItems > 0) ? _items[0] : _defaultItem;
   }

   [other methods omitted because they aren't relevant]

private:
   int _numItems;       // how many valid items (_items) points to
   ItemType * _items;   // demand-allocated
   const ItemType _defaultItem;
};
```

This class is really convenient to use -- any code can just #include "MyVector.h" and then start declaring objects of type MyVector and MyVector and so on, and it all Just Works (tm) without any futzing around required.

One thing that kind of bothers me, however, is the presence of the _defaultItem member variable, which is there solely to give GetFirstItemWithDefault() the ability to return a valid reference when the container is empty.  The objection is that if I declare N MyVector objects, that means N copies of _defaultItem will be present in RAM as well --- even though they are all identical and read-only, and so there really only needs to be one of them per process, not one per MyVector.

So, the obvious solution is to make _defaultItem static .... but AFAICT that comes with a cost:  if I do that, it is no longer possible for any old piece of code to simply #include "MyVector.h" and go... now the user has to be sure to declare storage for that static variable in one of his .cpp files, which is (a) a pain in the butt, and (b) means that the user of the code has to be aware of the details of the internal implementation of the class.  Since _defaultItem is a private member variable, the user of the class shouldn't have to think about it or even realize it exists, let alone know that he needs to declare storage for it.  (and what if two separate pieces of code both declare storage for it, each not knowing the other has done the same thing?  Wouldn't that cause a duplicate-symbol linker error?)

Therefore, my question is:  is there any way to tell C++ to automatically provide one unique storage (per instantiated type of MyVector) for this static member variable, so that users of MyVector don't have to know about it?  (Note that it would need to be automatic for all possible instantiations of MyVector<...>, not just for a few common cases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a template, the compiler will do the magic for you. Just put the static member in the header, and the compiler will see to that it is just instantiated once.

```
template <class ItemType> 
class MyVector
{
public:
    //...
private:
    static const ItemType _defaultItem;
}; 


template <class ItemType> 
const ItemType MyVector<ItemType>::_defaultItem;
```

Answer (score 8):

Why not make that default item static local to the function?

```
const ItemType & GetFirstItemWithDefault() const
{
    static const ItemType _default;
    return (_numItems > 0) ? _items[0] : _default;
}
```

This may not be what you want if you want to check against the default item in some other function again, but for that you can just put it in a seperate function aswell (that may be static itself):

```
static const ItemType& GetDefault() const
{
  static const ItemType _default;
  return _default;
}
```

And call that function when you need to access the default item.

---

That said, I think having a default item isn't really nice. `std::vector` also doesn't have it and doesn't need it. Just tell the user to check if the vector is `empty` and be done. One problem with hidden statics is, that you don't know `ItemType`. It could be a class that eats tons of resources and you just made another instance of that! Maybe rethink that class' design and after that, switch to a `std::vector`. :)

Comment: Simple, elegant, appropriate from how I read the question. +1

Comment: This pattern has a use. If most callers have to check for empty, but could equally function with just a default, then the overall code is simplified by having a form that returns a default.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: true, it can simplify certain code considerably, but need it be a member function? Does it justify a new Array class? You could e.g. create a `Defaulter` wrapper object, constructed with a reference to the `std::vector` or using composition, that substituted the default object as needed.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: That is in fact a well known patterh (Null object pattern), but in many cases it is better not to  have it as an internal detail of the method/class, but as part of the interface: `const ItemType& getWithDefault( int pos, const ItemType& def = ItemType() );` This way, the user can define in place their expected value: `intholder.getWithDefault( 0, -1 );` if you want this particular defaulted value to be `-1`, or just select what makes sense. If the object is expensive to create, use a pointer instead of a reference, null allowing for no default and throw if not present.

Answer (score 3):

> So, the obvious solution is to make
>   _defaultItem static .... but AFAICT that comes with a cost: if I do that,
>   it is no longer possible for any old
>   piece of code to simply #include
>   "MyArray.h" and go... now the user has
>   to be sure to declare storage for that
>   static variable in one of his .cpp
>   files, which is (a) a pain

**No**. This fear is out of concern. In `template`s you can (must) declare the `static` variable in the same file.

```
template <class ItemType> class MyVector
{
  const ItemType _defaultItem;
};
template <class ItemType>
const ItemType MyVector<ItemType>::_defaultItem; // ok (no multiple symbols)
```

Also, note that this `static` member will be instantiated only if `GetFirstItemWithDefault()` is called. So don't worry about redundant allocation also.

The only thing worry is to **provide default constructor** to all the `ItemType` as the `static` object will generically rely on the default constructor (which you must be caring about already, I guess). That's it.