# C++ Static member variable of class member instantiated twice

Tags: c++, templates, linker

I have a template class, which has two static member variables, one `int` and another an `std::array<volatile uint_fast32_t, 8>`. When I instantiate the template with two different classes (which are templates themselves) as template parameters, for one of the instantiations everything works perfectly, i.e. there is exactly one copy of both variables. However, for the other, the array appears in duplicate in the symbol table, and indeed my code has a bug that when I set a value in the array in one compilation unit, the change does not appear in another.

This is for an embedded system, which is the reason for this weird idiom of using static templates for a kind of compile-time polymorphism.

In code: Header declaring the class itself

```
//dacmux.h

namespace HAL {

template<typename dac_write_sequence_t,
    unsigned int chans,
    typename sample_t = uint_fast32_t>
struct dacmux {
private:

    typedef std::array<volatile sample_t, chans> chans_t;
    static chans_t channels;

    static unsigned int nextchan;
...
};

//The static variables defined here,
//count on the compiler/linker to make sure
//there is exactly one definition
template<typename dac_write_sequence_t,
    unsigned int chans,
    typename sample_t> 
   typename dacmux<dac_write_sequence_t, chans, sample_t>::chans_t dacmux<dac_write_sequence_t, chans, sample_t>::channels{0};

template<typename dac_write_sequence_t, unsigned int chans, typename sample_t> 
    unsigned int dacmux<dac_write_sequence_t, chans, sample_t>::nextchan = 0;

template<typename dac_t, typename addr_t, typename en_t>
struct muxed_setter {
    ...
};

template<typename dac_t>
struct dac_setter {
    ...
};

}//namespace HAL
```

A header which distributes definitions of the hardware:

```
//Hardware_types.h
...
//Multiplexer for the internal DAC
typedef HAL::dacmux<HAL::muxed_setter<dac1, mux1_addr, mux1_en>, 8> mux1;

//Sequencer for writing the external DAC values
typedef HAL::dacmux<HAL::dac_setter<extdac1>, 8> extdac_sequencer;
...
```

The header `Hardware_types.h` is included in two source files, `main.cpp`, `DebugConsole.cpp`, both of which use both `mux1` and `extdac_sequencer`.

As for as I understand, based on answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381872/is-it-possible-to-have-a-static-member-variable-in-my-templated-class-without-t) and many others, the compiler should take care that each of the static member variables is instantiated exactly once for each instantiation of the template?

However, when I set the values of `extdac_sequencer::channels` in `DebugConsole.cpp`, the changes are not reflected in an interrupt handler declared in `main.cpp`. The same works perfectly for `mux1::channels`. Indeed, an excerpt from the symbol table, extracted from the .elf by `objdump -t`:

```
20000280 l     O .bss   00000004 _ZN3HAL6dacmuxINS_10dac_setterINS_6ti_dacINS_3SPIINS_5SPI_2EEEN5GPIOs5pin_tINS6_1BELj12EEENS_12_GLOBAL__N_110xx68_frameENSA_12command_xx68ENSA_12channel_xx68EEEEELj8EjE8nextchanE
...
20000254 l     O .bss   00000020 _ZN3HAL6dacmuxINS_10dac_setterINS_6ti_dacINS_3SPIINS_5SPI_2EEEN5GPIOs5pin_tINS6_1BELj12EEENS_12_GLOBAL__N_110xx68_frameENSA_12command_xx68ENSA_12channel_xx68EEEEELj8EjE8channelsE
...
20000288 l     O .bss   00000020 _ZN3HAL6dacmuxINS_10dac_setterINS_6ti_dacINS_3SPIINS_5SPI_2EEEN5GPIOs5pin_tINS6_1BELj12EEENS_12_GLOBAL__N_110xx68_frameENSA_12command_xx68ENSA_12channel_xx68EEEEELj8EjE8channelsE
...
20000234  w    O .bss   00000020 _ZN3HAL6dacmuxINS_12muxed_setterIN4DACs11DAC_channelILj1EN5GPIOs5pin_tINS4_1AELj4EEEEENS4_12bit_stripe_tINS4_1CELj6ELj3EEENS5_ISA_Lj9EEEEELj8EjE8channelsE
...
2000027c  w    O .bss   00000004 _ZN3HAL6dacmuxINS_12muxed_setterIN4DACs11DAC_channelILj1EN5GPIOs5pin_tINS4_1AELj4EEEEENS4_12bit_stripe_tINS4_1CELj6ELj3EEENS5_ISA_Lj9EEEEELj8EjE8nextchanE
```

So the `nextchan` variable appears once per instantiation, as it should, and for `mux1` so does `channels`. However, for `extdac_sequencer`, the `channels` variable is repeated, which I believe explains the bug.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a compiler or linker bug?

Compiler: GCC arm-none-eabi 5.2.1 20151202

Linker: arm-none-eabi-ld 2.25.90.20151217

Linker options: `-T mem.ld -T libs.ld -T sections.ld -nostartfiles -Xlinker --gc-sections -L"../ldscripts" -Wl,-Map,"Synth1Firmware.map" -Xlinker --cref --specs=nano.specs`

### Update:

I've narrowed down the conditions for this to happen:

If the first template parameter of `dacmux` is not itself a template, everything works, i.e. no duplicate symbol:

```
struct extdac1_setter {
    template<typename sample_t>
    inline static void update(sample_t val, unsigned int addr) {
        extdac1::write_and_update(val, addr);
    }
};

//Multiplexer for external DAC, works
typedef HAL::dacmux<extdac1_setter, 8> extdac_sequencer;
```

However, if the template parameter is templated itself, I get the duplicate symbol problem:

```
template<typename dac_t>
struct dac_setter {
    template<typename sample_t>
    inline static void update(sample_t val, unsigned int addr) {
        dac_t::write_and_update(val, addr);
    }
};

//Multiplexer for external DAC, this produces a duplicate symbol
typedef HAL::dacmux<dac_setter<extdac1>, 8> extdac_sequencer;
```

Here, extdac1 is itself, again, a template:

```
typedef HAL::DAC8568<dacspi, typename dacspi::nss> extdac1;
```

...and `dacspi` is a template, and so on. Also, in the case which does work, with the other instantation, while `dac_write_sequence_t` is a template, it isn't anymore a template of templates. So I'm starting to think that this is a problem with template recursion depth, i.e. `ld` isn't looking deep enough.

A further interesting observation: on exactly the same condition as having the duplicate symbol, the Eclipse syntax highlighter says "invalid template parameters" on the line declaring `extdac_sequencer`, although the actual compilation step goes through.

Comment: I would say that this is a linker issue, not a compiler issue. The compiler did its job, and generated the symbols in each translation unit. It's the linker's job to throw away the duplicate symbols at link time.

Comment: Are you building a single executable or a bunch of shared objects?

Comment: @nm I'm building a single .elf, which is then flashed to the firmware

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you're probably right. Any ideas on how to make the linker behave correctly?

Comment: Also note that the duplicate *is* stripped correctly for the other instantiation.

Comment: In cases like these, I would start making random changes, trying to figure out what triggers the incorrect behavior. Anything from changing the order the object modules are linked at, to changing the length of the symbol name. Finally, the `binutils` bugzilla is down the hall, last door on your right.

Comment: @Timo I know it might sound silly but are you sure you include into your header file `#ifndef` `#define` `#endif` directives? It could explain the weird linker behaviour, especially if you include `dacmux.h` more than once...

Comment: What's your ld command? Also try instantiating the static members explicitly. Not fun but should work more reliably.

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg I just double checked, and I do have include guards in place.

Comment: @n.m. see my update, I've listed the linker options. Also, I already found a not-too-bad workaround (also mentioned in the update), although I'm still interested in why the original version didn't work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I did random changing, and was indeed able to narrow down the problem a little, see my update to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was my sillyness: I was using an unnamed namespace in a header that defines the template HAL::DAC8568, which is defined as

```
template<typename spi_t, typename nss_t> using DAC8568 = ti_dac<spi_t, nss_t,
                        xx68_frame,
                        command_xx68,
                        channel_xx68>;
```

Here `xx68_frame`, `command_xx68`, and `channel_xx68` are all defined in the unnamed namespace (which is of course the wrong thing to do in a header). This of course means that when instantiated from a different compilation unit, I get a *different type* for each of them and therefore a *different type* for DAC8568 and so on, so it's perfectly natural to get another instance of the static variable.

Changing the unnamed namespace to `namespace detail` fixed the problem immediately.

I am still somewhat baffled by the fact that the mangled names in the linker output seem identical. How can that be?

Anyway, we learn from this the following (some of which we knew already):

1. I'm an instantiation of the *simpleton* -pattern
2. unnamed namespaces in headers are truly evil
3. bugs stemming from the above can be quite subtle